# Complex Roots of equation in Python

Tags: python, math, scipy, sympy

I am trying to solve the following equation,

```
def f(u1, u2, u3, u4, a11, a16, a12, a66, a26, a22):
    return a11*u4-2*a16*u3+(2*a12+a66)*u2-2*a26*u1+a22
```

where `u1` to `u4` are complex variables that I want the root for `f() = 0` and `a11` to `a66` are arguments(`floats`) that need to be passed into the function.  I have looked at `scipy.optimize.fsolve()` and `sympy` but couldn't get either method to work correctly.

Comment: Please explain what you expected and how `scipy.optimize.fsolve()` and `sympy` differed from that.

Comment: If either method works correctly, maybe you could start by trying a simpler function (e.g. f(x) = x**2 + 1). Starting by difficult examples only introduces entropy on the solution attempt....

Comment: I could not get my code to run due errors with the the format in the args=() or errors like this,      print scipy.optimize.fsolve(f, x, 100.0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 115, in f
solve
    _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 13, in _c
heck_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
TypeError: 'file' object is not callable

Comment: the code,    x=[complex(1.0),complex(2.0),complex(3.0),complex(4.0)]#root guess
   print scipy.optimize.fsolve(f, x, 100.0)

Comment: The equation appears in http://www.springerlink.com/content/j6g31x25651g5333/ in eq. 4.

Comment: Please edit that code and error message back into the question: it is unnecessarily hard to read when it is in a comment.

Comment: I'm guessing that what user1336227 wants are four roots of a real 4th degree polynomial (the roots therefore appearing in conjugate pairs).

Answer (score 3):

You have one linear equation for four variables, therefore you do not have a unique solution. Any point in the hyperplane of solutions in C^4 would make your function zero.

If you do not have any other constrains the only thing you can do is to express one of those U-variables as an obvious linear function of the rest.

sympy.solve will do exactly that:

```
In [1]: solve('a11*u4-2*a16*u3+(2*a12+a66)*u2-2*a26*u1+a22', 'u1')
Out[1]: 

⎡a₁₁⋅u₄ + 2⋅a₁₂⋅u₂ - 2⋅a₁₆⋅u₃ + a₂₂ + a₆₆⋅u₂⎤
⎢───────────────────────────────────────────⎥
⎣                   2⋅a₂₆                   ⎦
```

Numerical routines from scipy will not converge, as the solutions form a hyperplane.

Comment: I have used strings for the input to save some lines of code, but if this is a part of a program you should define your symbols.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am not that familiar with the mathematics involved in the anisotropic elasticity and fracture mechanics that I am trying to solve for.  In the text cited previously it states, "the roots of u are always complex or purely imaginary and will occur in conjugate pairs...".  Does this change your answer?  I need the roots of u1 and u2 to solve eq. 26a from the text.